# Malloc a pointer to a pointer to a structure array by reference

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, pointers, malloc

The code below compiles, but immediately crashes for reasons obvious to others, but not to me. I can't seem to get it right, can anyone tell me how to fix this.

```
*array_ref[2] = array[0];
*array_ref[3] = array[1];
```

It crashes on that part everytime.

```
typedef struct test {
    char *name;
    char *last_name;
} person;



int setName(person ** array, person ***array_ref) {

    *array = malloc (5 * sizeof(person));
    *array_ref= malloc(5 * sizeof(person*));

   array[0]->name = strdup("Bob");
   array[1]->name = strdup("Joseph");
   array[0]->last_name = strdup("Robert");
   array[1]->last_name = strdup("Clark");


*array_ref[2] = array[0];
*array_ref[3] = array[1];


    return 1;
}



int main()
{
    person *array;
    person **array_r;

   setName(&array,&array_r);

    printf("First name is %s %s\n", array[0].name, array[0].last_name);
    printf("Second name is %s %s\n", array_r[3]->name, array_r[3]->last_name);

     while(1) {}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What you should usually do in a case where your code has a bug, especially when the bug is an actual crash and happens every time, is to try and narrow it down to the least amount of code that still makes it happen.

This will make it both easier for others to find the bug when looking at the code, and more importantly,  much easier for **you** to understand what exactly is causing the crash.

Comment: @Edan, I wouldn't say that it's an issue in this case. There isn't much code here, and the problem is fairly clear.

Comment: +1 Edan.  Narrowing this down to remove `array_ref` clarifies the problem and would surely help ZPS understand it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operator `[]` has higher precedence than unary `operator*`. Hence, this:

```
*array_ref[2] = array[0];
*array_ref[3] = array[1];
```

actually means:

```
*(array_ref[2]) = array[0];
*(array_ref[3]) = array[1];
```

Types are correct here, which is why it compiles. But from your code it's clear that your intent actually was:

```
(*array_ref)[2] = array[0];
(*array_ref)[3] = array[1];
```

So just use parentheses.

Comment: Remember `array[1]` is not allocated :).

Answer (score 1):

You allocated space for the array_ref pointers, but not for what they point to.

Comment: He points them to objects which are allocated, this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the following in setName()

```
 *array_ref[2] = array[0];
 *array_ref[3] = array[1];
```

to

```
*(*array_ref+2) = array[0];
*(*array_ref+3) = array[1];
```

This works.

Answer (score 1):

`array[1]->name` is your problem.  This should be `(*array)[1].name`.  Notice how the two aren't equivalent.  All the similar uses have the same problem, except for `[0]`, which accidentally does the right thing.

Remember that `array`, the function parameter, *isn't* your array, it's a pointer to your array.

Answer (score 1):

In functions like this I prefer code like:

```
int setName(person ** out_array, person ***out_array_ref) {
    person* array = malloc(5 * sizeof(person));
    person** array_ref = malloc(5 * sizeof(person*));
    array[0].name = strdup("Bob");
    array[1].name = strdup("Joseph");
    array[0].last_name = strdup("Robert");
    array[1].last_name = strdup("Clark");
    // I'm guessing this was your intent for array_ref, here:
    array_ref[2] = &array[0];
    array_ref[3] = &array[1];

    *out_array = out_array;
    *out_array_ref = array_ref;
    return 1;
}
```

Note that this catches both `array[1]->name` as noted by Roger Pate, and `*array_ref[2] = array[0]` as (almost) noted by Pavel - whose solution (*array_ref)[2] = array[0] assigns from an unallocated `person*` `array[1]` - both of which are hard to notice with the extra dereference.

Of course, I mostly do this because I use C++, and this increases exception safety ;).